# Rendere in italiano `scunire` i panni

Tags: verbs, translation, regional

Qual è l'italiano per `scunire` i panni (appendere i panni in terrazzo finché sgocciolano poi magari portarli in lavanderia al chiuso).

`Scunire` proviene da un dialetto emiliano e da chissà quanti altri dialetti padani e non.

Comment: Non risponde alla domanda, ma può essere interessante: il *Dizionario etimologico dei dialetti italiani* di Manlio Cortelazzo e Carla Marcato ha la voce:  
**sconìrse,** v. rifl. (veneto; veneto istriano: *sconìr*, *scunìr*), ‘smagrire, deperire’, ‘sfasciarsi’; (emiliano: *sconìr*), ‘gocciolare, scolare’; (lunigianese: *scunire*) ‘diminuire’.  
Dal latino parlato * *exconicĕre* ‘levare, togliere’, da *conicĕre* ‘versare’; nel veneto anche col prefisso *de-*: *desconirse*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non concordo con la risposta di Iserni.

"Sgocciolare" [è sia transitivo che intransitivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sgocciolare/) (non solo il Treccani lo riporta come tale, anche il mio Devoto-Oli edizione del 1971 lo riporta sia come transitivo che come intransitivo; magari più tardi aggiungo una foto per cr), quindi "sgocciolare i panni" è tanto corretto quanto "mettere i panni a sgocciolare".

In Toscana usiamo anche "sgrondare" (che con mia sorpresa non è riportato come regionale, nemmeno dal Devoto-Oli), che [è altrettanto sia transitivo che intransitivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sgrondare/) (di nuovo, non solo il Treccani lo riporta come tale, anche il mio Devoto-Oli edizione del 1971 lo riporta sia come transitivo che come intransitivo), il che rende corretto anche "sgrondare i panni" / "mettere i panni a sgrondare".

Comunque se l'intento è semplicemente quello di intendersi credo che il modo più comune di esprimere l'azione sia di dire "stendere i panni" (tecnicamente solo transitivo, in Toscana usiamo sbagliando anche "mettere i panni a stendere").

Non è proprio la stessa cosa perchè non implica lo sgocciolamento, ma ritengo sia il modo più comune di esprimere l'azione (e oltretutto non l'ho mai sentito usare per descrivere qualcos'altro, quindi credo che non ci sia nemmeno il rischio di essere ambigui).

Answer (score 4):

Non esiste un verbo transitivo, che io sappia.

Si usa invece colloquialmente "sgocciolare i panni" (che in realtà non sarebbe corretto, perché i panni sgocciolano, non sono sgocciolati), oppure "appendere i panni a sgocciolare".